# BLDC high-side MOSFET switching - bootstrap confusion

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, driver, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm designing a motor driver and I have had too many MOSFET explosions lately.

Following the typical application guide on [ROHMs data sheet](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/gate_driver/bd2320efj-la-e.pdf), I am confused on whether I need to actually bootstrap the high-side MOSFET or not. The [MOSFET](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FQU13N10L_D-1810105.pdf)'s datasheet says the gate-source voltage is 20 V and the gate threshold voltage is 2 V.

I take that to mean that at least 2 V is required to switch the MOSFET. I have the driver Vcc on a separate 12 V buck. My MCU outputs a 5 V PWM signal to the driver, powered by its own buck as well.

Questions:

- Is the Vcc supply of 12v enough for the driver to switch the high-side MOSFET, or do I need to bootstrap as in my schematic? I calculated the capacitor based on the data sheet formulas.
- Typically, why does the high-side require a higher voltage to switch? Is it a higher voltage than the Vcc to the driver or a higher voltage than the drain voltage on the MOSFET (52 V)?
- Is switching the high-side difficult because the higher voltage acts like a flood gate where we need much more power to open the door that has lots of pressure against it? (maybe a bad analogy)
- When the low side is on, the capacitor charges and acts like a charge pump. So is the voltage on the HO pin really above 52 V to switch the high-side? Wouldn't that damage the MOSFET given the rating for the gate is 20 V max?
- Should my MCU GND also be connected to the GND of the driver to close the circuit on the PWM?
- Should the GND of the low-side MOSFET also be connected to the GND of the driver to close the circuit on the HO pin? This may be wrong in my schematic, I am trying to understand how the output signal of the driver closes to switch the MOSFET. I have all the grounds connected which might be totally incorrect.

[image]

Comment: "I take that to mean that at least 2v is required to switch the MOSFET"  No, that's the voltage you need to just start conducting 250 uA.  To get low RDSon, see the datasheet specs for Vgs = 5 V and Vgs = 10 V.

Comment: Also, if Q1 is on, your Phase A voltage (Q1 source) will be pretty close to 52 V, correct?  And if you want the gate TO SOURCE voltage of Q1 to be 5 - 10 V, what voltage will you need at the gate?  Where will that voltage come from without the bootstrap circuit?  The 20 V max Vgs rating is with respect to the source, not ground.

Comment: \$V_{GS_{th}}  max\$ is *not* the gate-source voltage where a switching MOSFET is "fully on" - below \$V_{GS_{th}}  min\$, it is *off for practical purposes*.

Comment: I think you need to brush up on why bootstrapping is used.

Comment: I am here asking these questions for a reason. I have been reading through a lot, but some of us need to speak with the professor during office hours :) or get tutoring. 

I understand the bootstrap is used to bias the voltage higher to switch on. I was hoping for an example that specifically helps me understand why the high-side is difficult to switch. Yes to 52v at the source. I was assuming that HO would output the Vcc voltage which is what happens with the low-side correct? So with bootstrapping the voltage at HO is above 52v? Always above the drain voltage to switch?

Comment: (Never below the *drain voltage to switch*. Well above with HIN high *and* the boost capacitor charged.)

Comment: Ok thank you. Just a couple things...

As a visual reference for me personally, the reason for "never below the drain voltage to switch"...can my flood gate analogy be applied here? So the high-side always needs more help/power to switch/open? (for the gate to attract the electrons)

Does my schematic look fine? Anything burning before I go ahead with it?

Comment: As you know, voltage is always measured between two points. Let's say 2V for example (even though the MOSFET isn't properly turned on at that voltage). The MOSFET turns on very slightly at 2V; which two points does the MOSFET use to measure the 2V ?

Comment: From the gate to source which is connected to ground.